# How To Make VBA Macro Form Extensible?

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks, contentcontrol

Context:

I am relatively new to using VBA macros, especially for developing macros for MS Word documents. Today I played around with a little project that I found would be useful for myself as I have been involved in sponsorship efforts for clubs at my school, and this is a great and simple way to manage the information I need to keep track of. (This form simply generates a pdf that I can send to companies that sponsor my club. I also plan to store this information in an excel sheet for easy record keeping and fund tracking!)

What I am looking for guidance on is what would be the best way to make the Item section at the bottom (the table) flexible, in that:

if a company were to sponsor us multiple things (say 1 monetary donation of $500 and then 10 pieces of building material), what would be the best way to ADD new content controls for the additional items? I currently have the form setup so that I can handle 1 type of donation.

I understand that I could add new content controls in the template file, and then use conditional controls on the form to add additional donation types/amounts to those content controls where needed but I was wondering if there was something more elegant than just "hiding" the content controls in plain sight? As in I create them ONLY when I need them, as opposed to having them there in the template already, and going possibly unused.

I also understand that I could create bookmarks in my template, and then enter information at those bookmark locations based on conditional controls from my form, but I feel like that's a similar situation to the one above, although perhaps a bit "cleaner".

Any advice on how to add in new content controls or bookmarks ONLY as needed would be much appreciated, as I would like to ensure as I pick up more and new VBA skills that I am using good practices and trying to push myself early on.

Screenshot of Invoice Template and User Form

[image]

Comment: You could use Excel or a database like Access to generate/store the data from the beginning (as you mentioned). Doing it from a UserForm in Word, maybe look for a listbox and try to populate, store the information there and use the bookmarks to update it.

Comment: In the past I've done as @Ricardo Diaz suggested and it worked well.  I recommend looking into "mail merge" functionality.

Comment: You could revise your form so that the single Sponsorship Information part is replaced by a tab strip so that you can have multiple sponsorship items per form.

Comment: @n8, thank you for recommending I look into mail merge. I can see that functionality being extremely useful, especially as these invoices will be e-mailed out. It gives me more to think about...

Comment: @freeflow, could you explain what you mean by tab strip? I bet that I would recognize what you are referring to, but I don't get the terminology. My apologies.

Comment: I used mail merge to produce PDFs and to save them to file paths, it's not necessary to email out, necessarily.

Comment: @onderijw  Tab strips are a control item you can use on a form.  The are a standard part of the VB IDE form designer.  Even a tiny amount of googling would have meant you didn't need to ask that question.

Comment: Which version(s) of Word are we dealing with, here? There's a special kind of content control in Word 2013 and newer that will create a copy of itself (also an entire table row) when the user tabs out of it...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of employing a userform you could probably do the whole job in the document itself, using content controls in a table, with a macro like the following that gets triggered when you exit the last content control in the table. The macro gets inserted into the document's 'ThisDocument' code module:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
'The following code conditionally adds a new row, with content controls, to the designated table.
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Prot As Variant
Const Pwd As String = "" 'Insert password (if any) here
'Bookmarking the table provides the flexibility of being able to deal with the addition/deletion
' of other tables before the one we want to process.
Const StrBkMk As String = "TblBkMk"
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(StrBkMk) = False Then
    MsgBox "The table bookmark: '" & StrBkMk & "' is missing." & vbCr & _
    "Please add it to the relevant table before continuing.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
End With
With CCtrl
  'Check that the Content Control is within our bookmarked range.
  ' One could test for a particular table instead
  If .Range.InRange(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range) = False Then Exit Sub
  'Get the number of ContentControls in the table
  i = .Range.Tables(1).Range.ContentControls.Count
  'Get our ContentControl's index # in the table
  j = ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Tables(1).Range.Start, .Range.End).ContentControls.Count
  'Check that we're using the last content control
  If i <> j Then Exit Sub
End With
'Solicit user input
If MsgBox("Add new row?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
With ActiveDocument
  ' Un-protect the document, if applicable
  Prot = .ProtectionType
  If .ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    Prot = .ProtectionType
    .Unprotect Password:=Pwd
  End If
  With Selection.Tables(1).Rows
    'Insert an empty paragraph after our table, then replace it with a replica of the last row
    With .Last.Range
      .Next.InsertBefore vbCr
      .Next.FormattedText = .FormattedText
    End With
    'Reset all content controls in the new last row
    For Each CCtrl In .Last.Range.ContentControls
      With CCtrl
        If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then .Checked = False
        If .Type = wdContentControlRichText Or .Type = wdContentControlText Then .Range.Text = ""
        If .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList Then .DropdownListEntries(1).Select
        If .Type = wdContentControlComboBox Then .DropdownListEntries(1).Select
        If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then .Range.Text = ""
      End With
    Next
  End With
  ' Re-protect the document, if applicable
  .Protect Type:=Prot, Password:=Pwd
End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** The above code assumes the table is bookmarked 'TblBkMk'. As per the comments in the code, this allows for the possibility that other tables might be inserted/deleted before the one you're interested in. If you're not concerned about that, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989

For some demo documents, see:

- https://www.msofficeforums.com/38461-post10.html
- https://www.msofficeforums.com/145675-post4.html
- https://www.msofficeforums.com/148210-post11.html

Comment: Your answer makes we wonder: am I interpreting content controls wrong?

Are content controls supposed to be more formal and potentially permanent ways to enter info into a word doc as OPPOSED to using a form? Is assigning text box values to content controls redundant?

Anyway, your solution did inspire a solution that I think works for my current ability - I have added 'Add' and 'Delete' buttons. The 'Add' button captures data and inputs it into table cells in a new row. If I mistakenly add a row, I use the 'Delete' button. As a beginner, this does the trick for me :) Thank you!

Comment: Content controls are just another means of achieving the same ends. One advantage they have over a userform is that you can add items to a dropodown or combobox without the need for code, which also means they don't need to be reloaded each time you open the document *and* your last selection is retained.